# testfields user input does not get into firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason my textfields are empty in my firebase database... I dont get my user input. First day of using firebase, I might have missed something simple..

```
var tickets = [Ticket]()





func test() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("tickets")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()



    guard let Price = emailTextField.text, ticketName = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }


    let values: [String: AnyObject] = ["Price": Price, "ticketName": ticketName]

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        let ticketId = snapshot.key
        let ticksRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("tickets").child(ticketId)
        ticksRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                           guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }

            self.messages.append(Ticket(dictionary: dictionary))

            childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by : *my textfields are empty in my firebase database*

Comment: I mean in firebase I can not see what the user inputs from the textfields are... they just have "" and nothing else

Comment: Try printing those textfield's just before you save to FBDB, do you get nil?

Comment: Thank you! I did the printing and realized the function was being called before the user had typed any value into the textfield... dummy me...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I realized my function was being called before the user had written anything into the textfield and that is why my database didnt get the user input.